# Is record class or class preferred if model is used with ADO.NET, but usage of EF is considered in future

Tags: c#, class, model, record

I've created a DB in which all the operations are handled by stored procedures. I need to write a library for my colleague to use for his website later on. Although, for now, this library is supposed to be used with `BackgroundService` (collects data by OPC), there are different entities there.

There are lots of articles saying that records are used as DTO, while EF easily works with classes as they are mutable and reference based. But I stuck with the way I should choose now. If I my entity is record, operations like get all records from table are easier with it, but if I add validation and there is consideration to use EF or maybe Dapper in future classes seem to be more suitable.

It's also interesting to know if having both classes and their record counterparts at the same time is that bad?

```
/* Department.cs */
namespace DB.Models;

public class Department
{
  private readonly short _id;

  public short ID { 
    get => _id; 
    init {
      if (value < 0) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(ID)} cannot be negative", nameof(ID));
      _id = value;
    }
  }

  private readonly short _itid;
  
  public short ITID { 
    get => _itid; 
    init {
      if (value < 0) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(ITID)} cannot be negative", nameof(ITID));
      _itid = value;
    }
  }
  
  private readonly string _name;
  
  public string Name { 
    get => _name; 
    init {
      if (value is null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Name), $"{nameof(Name)} cannot be null");
      if (value.All(char.IsWhiteSpace))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(Name)} cannot be whitespace", nameof(Name));
      _name = value;
    } 
  }
  
  private readonly string? _description;

  public string? Description { 
    get => _description; 
    init {
      if (value is not null && value.All(char.IsWhiteSpace))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(Department)} cannot be whitespace", nameof(Department));
      _description = value;
    } 
  }
  
  public Department(short id, short itid, string name, string? description)
  {
    ID = id;
    ITID = itid;
    Name = name;
    Description = description;
  }
}

/* MZTP.cs */
namespace DB;

public class MZTP
{
// constructor, properties and other methods of the class
public async Task<List<Department>?> GetDepartments()
  {
      List<Department>? departments = new(); 
      try 
      {
          using (FbConnection con = new(ConfigConnectionString)) 
          {
              con.Open();

              using (FbCommand cmd = new() { CommandText = "GET_DEPARTMENTS", Connection = con, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) 
              {
                  FbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                  if (!reader.HasRows) 
                      return departments;

                  while (await reader.ReadAsync()) 
                  {
                      var id = reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("ID"));
                      var itid = reader.GetInt16(reader.GetOrdinal("ITID"));
                      var name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("NAME"));
                      var descrOrdinal = reader.GetOrdinal("DESCRIPTION");
                      var description = (await reader.IsDBNullAsync(descrOrdinal))
                                                   ? null
                                                   : reader.GetString(descrOrdinal);

                      departments.Add(new Department(id, itid, name, description));
                  }
              }
          }
          return departments;
      } 
      catch (Exception err) 
      {
          ErrorMessage = err.Message;
          departments = null;
      }

      return departments;
  }

  public async Task<short?> UpdateDepartment(Department department)
  {
    try 
    {
      using (FbConnection con = new(ConfigConnectionString)) 
      {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new() { CommandText = "UPDATE_DEPARTMENT", Connection = con, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) 
        {
          cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new FbParameter[] {
            new FbParameter("@ID", department.ID),
            new FbParameter("@ITID", department.ITID),
            new FbParameter("@NAME", department.Name),
            new FbParameter("@DESCRIPTION", department.Description)
          });

          if (await cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync() is short id) 
          {
            return id;
          }
          else 
          {
            return null;
          } 
        }
      }
    } 
    catch (Exception err) 
    {
      ErrorMessage = err.Message;
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Presumably its not bad. But if you foresee moving on to one of-the-shelf ORMs in the future having the validation backed in into the model classes may become a problem.

Comment: @Ralf as far as I use ADO.NET at the moment and procedures will raise errors if, for instance, I pass invalid type to them, I need no validation. I should use classes cause dapper needs classes rather than value equal records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bad" is subjective. Does it achieve what you want without imposing too many negative consequences, where both the positives and negatives are specific to your usage? Great! Do that!

What I *will* say is that there is almost no benefit in writing your own command/reader code; that's just "busy work" - tools like Dapper can replace most of that code with 1-line.

Comment: So, class or record on this stage?

Comment: Yes, absolutely